# How large is the Monero's sync file?

Tags: blocksize

Just wondering, how large is it?

I am kind of on a limited data plan here so I was wondering if I cold be able to download the whole thing before running out of bandwidth.

Comment: is sync file = blockchain? or blockchain is something else?

Answer (score 2):

It's at 14.3GB (16-Jul 2017)

If you're already partially synced, you can first generate the .raw file from the data you already have:

`monero-blockchain-export`

and then continue downloading only what's missing:

```
wget -c -O ~/.bitmonero/export/blockchain.raw https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw
```

and finally import the now full .raw file

`monero-blockchain-import`